# Creating a composite string sourced from multiple places in a JSON document

Tags: jq, yq

Consider this JSON document

```
echo '
{
    "alpha": {
        "id": "id1",
        "values": [
            "one",
            "two"
        ]
    },

    "beta": {
        "id": "id2",
        "values": [
            "three"
        ]
    }  
}
' >data.json
```

check syntax

```
$ yq -p json -P -o j 'true  ' data.json 
true
```

I want to generate a series of strings that combines the `id` field with each of the `values`. So output I need should look like this

```
"id1-one"
"id1-two"
"id2-three"
```

This is what I've tried

```
$ yq -p json -P -o j '.[] | .id as $ID | .values[] | $ID + "-" + . ' data.json
"id1-one"
"id2-one"
"id1-two"
"id2-two"
"id1-three"
"id2-three"
```

There seems to be a multiplication factor kicking in with the `$ID` variable. Is this the correct approach to get attributes from a different scope, or is there a cleaner way to achieve this?

Note -- the real JSON document contains a lot more nesting, so there are multiple nested arrays/objects between the `values` and the `id` attributes.

One final point. I tried the same code with `jq` and it worked fine.

```
$ jq ' .[] | .id as $ID | .values[] | $ID + "-" + .  ' data.json
"id1-one"
"id1-two"
"id2-three"
```

Comment: Your input is JSON; your output is JSON – why not use `jq`? Or is this question more about "it works in jq, why doesn't it in yq?"?

Comment: @pmqs If you don't want to use jq because somewhere else you also need yaml support, know that both [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) (which is the [other implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info) of yq) as well as [itchyny/gojq](https://github.com/itchyny/gojq) do support (at least) both json *and* yaml, while your original filter that *does* use the variable also works in them as expected and without modifications (tested with yq 3.1.0 and gojq 0.12.11).

Comment: @knittl - have requirements to deal with both yaml & json, so focusing on one tool if possible. Secondary issue is why it works qith `jq` and not with `yq`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need that variable elsewhere? Because it just works without:

```bash
yq -p json -P -o json '.[] | .id + "-" + .values[]' data.json
```

```json
"id1-one"
"id1-two"
"id2-three"
```

Tested with mikefarah/yq version v4.30.5

Comment: Thanks @pmf  -- the `.id + "-" + .values[]` syntax was the part I was missing, Plugged that syntax into the real application & it worked fine. Need to take another look at the documentation.  The tutorials I've seen for both are good for very simple queries, but this syntax passed me by.